# ADF-how to compare two get metadata activity results and skip if the same name exists

Tags: azure-data-factory

Just wondering if someone could help me with a problem I have
I am trying to set up a Pipeline to download files from an FTP Server into Blob

I have 2 get metadata activities 1 to get the filenames from Sftp site and other one to bring the files form Blob storage. I need to compare the results of both the activities and pick  only the files which are not processed.

Example:

**Get Metadata Activity 1 results:**
{"childItems": [ {"name": "2022.txt", "type": "File" }]}

**Getmetadata activity 2 results:**
{"childItems": [ {"name": "2022.txt", "type": "File" }]}

I need to match the childItems.name of both the activities and if the same file contains in both the activities then Skip the process, if not exists then process that file
Any help?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Filter activity** to get the required files list.

Please go through a sample demonstration below.

**These are my source files from first Get Meta Data:**

[image]

**Files from target Meta data activity:**

[image]

Now use Filter and give Source child items as Items. `@activity('files from source').output.childItems`

[image]

For condition give the below expression.

```
@not(contains(activity('files from target').output.childItems,item()))
```

This condition will give the list of Source files which are not exists in the Target files as array.

[image]

**Filter Result:**

[image]

You can use this array as `@activity('Filter1').output.Value` as per your requirement.