# How to compare output of two get metadata

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am quite new in adf and I have the following condition.
I have a source and a destination.
I want to build a logic where if file is prent in target it should not copy the file from source else it should copy the source file.
The source and sink are different so with two getmetadata I am trying to get the files with childite.
With a set variable activity I am passing the output of get metadatas for comparison.
I am failing at the logic stage.
Please let me know if any other better approach is possible

Logic:If file is present in destination it should not copy file from source else it should copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Filter activity

In items : @activity('files from source').output.childItems
Conditions: @not(contains(activity('files from target').output.childItems,item()))

similar thread: [ADF-how to compare two get metadata activity results and skip if the same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833488/adf-how-to-compare-two-get-metadata-activity-results-and-skip-if-the-same-name-e)